# Input Select doesn't understand first option

Tags: html, angular, components, html-select

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6. I'm using the **bootstrap-select** library (by Silvio Mureto) to create a custom component (it represents a combo-box).
Unfortunately, even if the first option of the combo-box is selected, 
if the component is inserted in a form with the relative submit button, the object `form.value` is not connected to any instance!
This is the template code that uses the custom component:

```
  <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit) = onSubmit(form.value)>

    <custom-component 
      name='value'
      [options]="proveUrl2"
      ngModel
      >
      </custom-component>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

  </form>
```

The object proveUrl2 is this:

```
this.proveUrl2 = [
  {label: 'Value 1', value: '1'},
  {label: 'Value 2', value: '2'},
  {label: 'Value 3', value: '3'},
  {label: 'Value 4', value: '4'}
];
```

The code of the customponent is quite complex, 
I only say that I added this for the two-way binding:

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomComponent),
        multi: true
    }]
```

This is the problem: If I have a select without `title`, the first option is selected by default:
[image]

but if I click the submit button, this appears on the console:

[image]

As if the first option was not detected! 
If I select another option, everything works perfectly, even if I reselect `value1`.

Comment: `(ngSubmit) = onSubmit(form.value)` should be `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)"`

Comment: This doesn't change anything!

Comment: It's not fix for your problem, it's just code correction. Calm down. Add `selected` to first option.

Comment: quiet, it was just to emphasize... anyway, it's useless to put "selected" in the first option. 
I think the problem is due to the Angular form and not the component